# Can I apply for tourist visa to USA if I am holding Mexico Work Visa as a Indian Citizen

Tags: visas, usa, tourist-visas, mexico, working-visas

I will be in Mexico some time around this year with Temporary Work Visa. Is it possible to apply USA Tourist Visa while am in Mexico with Temporary Work Visa as a Indian Citizen?

Comment: You might want to take into account Midavalo's comment below and see whether you can get your visa where you live now or on your way to the US.  Appointments are hard to come by these days in most of the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a work visa from Mexico will neither aid you nor would be a deterrent in your application for a US tourist visa. Just apply as usual by filling form DS-160 and appearing for a personal interview at a US embassy or consulate closest to where you live in Mexico. There is nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: More to the point, US consulates in Mexico and Canada explicitly allow 3rd country citizens to apply there even during temporary presence

Comment: It would be worth noting that wait times for visa interviews at US consulates in Mexico are well over 1 year

Comment: In fact, the estimated wait time for an interview at the Tijuana US Consulate is "513 calendar days"  - See [Visa Appointment Wait Times](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html) and select a US Consulate